# What is a commutative infinity-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, higher-category-theory, hochschild-cohomology

In the nLab article on [Hochschild cohomology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hochschild+cohomology) it says

> Thus, for $A$ a commutative $\infty$-algebra, its *Hochschild homology complex* is its $(\infty,1)$-tensoring $S^1\cdot A$ with the $\infty$-groupoid incarnation of the circle.

I couldn't find anything online on the notion of a commutative $\infty$-algebra. What is such an object? References are welcome.

Comment: The article you link to [links to an online resource for that](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/infinity-algebra+over+an+%28infinity%2C1%29-algebraic+theory) which admittedly redirects immediately to another article... still, that counts as something to read through I think.

Comment: This is referring to an $E_{\infty}$ algebra: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/E-infinity+algebra